# ROT 13 Cipher: Creating a Function Python

Tags: python-2.7, encryption, caesar-cipher, rot13

I need to create a function that replaces a letter with the letter 13 letters after it in the alphabet (without using encode). I'm relatively new to Python so it has taken me a while to figure out a way to do this without using Encode.

Here's what I have so far. When I use this to type in a normal word like "hello" it works but if I pass through a sentence with special characters I can't figure out how to **JUST** include letters of the alphabet and skip numbers, spaces or special characters completely.

```
def rot13(b):
    b = b.lower()
    a = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)]
    c = []
    d = []
    x = a[0:13]
    for i in b:
        c.append(a.index(i))
    for i in c:
        if i <= 13:
            d.append(a[i::13][1])
        elif i > 13:
            y = len(a[i:])
            z = len(x)- y
            d.append(a[z::13][0])
    e = ''.join(d)
    return e
```

**EDIT**

I tried using .isalpha() but this doesn't seem to be working for me - characters are duplicating for some reason when I use it. Is the following format correct:

```
def rot13(b):
    b1 = b.lower()
    a = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)]
    c = []
    d = []
    x = a[0:13]
    for i in b1:
        if i.isalpha():
            c.append(a.index(i))
            for i in c:
                if i <= 12:
                    d.append(a[i::13][1])
                elif i > 12:
                    y = len(a[i:])
                    z = len(x)- y
                    d.append(a[z::13][0])
        else:
            d.append(i)
    if message[0].istitle() == True:
        d[0] = d[0].upper()
    e = ''.join(d)
    return e
```

Comment: Perhaps an if check for `character.isalpha()` would help here? where `character` is replaced with whatever vaiable you're using to hold the character

Comment: This sounds like a problem easily solved with a regex.

Comment: Hi @LukeK I tried using character.isalpha() as you suggested. Could you please take a look at my Edit and let me know what I'm doing wrong? For some reason the text I enter into the function is duplicating a lot when I use .isalpha()

Comment: See answer posted below. The TL;DR is that you have an unnecessary loop and a weird way of doing things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from comments. OP was advised to use isalpha, and wondering why that's causing duplication (see OP's edit)

This isn't tied to the use of `isalpha`, it's to do with the second for loop

```
for i in c:
```

isn't necessary, and is causing the duplication. You should remove that. Instead you can do the same by just using `index = a.index(i)`. You were already doing this, but for some reason appending to a list instead and causing confusion

Use the `index` variable any time you would have used `i` inside the `for i in c` loop. On a side note, in nested for loops try not to reuse the same variables. It just causes confusion...but that's a matter for code review

Assuming you do all that right it should work.